# Using an STL map, wrong number of template arguments?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I'm having a little trouble utilizing a map, and I have never really used them before so I am really struggling here

My Code is as follows:

MSTapp.h

```
 5 #ifndef MSTAPP_H
 6 #define MSTAPP_H
 7
 8 #include"Graph.h"
 9
 10 #include<iostream>
 11 #include<map>
 12 #include<vector>
 13 #include<string>
 14
 15 using namespace std;
 16
 17 class MSTapp
 18 {
 19  public:
 20   void read_graph();
 21   void print_v();
 22 //  void print_e();
 23
 24  private:
 25    Graph my_graph;
 26 };
 27
 28 #endif
 29
```

MSTapp.cpp

```
 5 #include"MSTapp.h"
 6 #include"Graph.h"
 7
 8 #include<iostream>
 9 #include<map>
 10 #include<vector>
 11 #include<stdlib.h>
 12 #include<sstream>
 13 #include<string>
 14
 15 using namespace std;
 16
 17 void MSTapp::read_graph()
 18 {
 19  string s;
 20  int count = 0;
 21
 22  while(getline(cin, s))
 23  {
 24   if(count == 0)
 25   {
 26    istringstream my_words(s);
 27    string word;
 28    while(my_words >> word)
 29    {
 30     my_graph.add_vertex(word);
 31    }
 32   }
 33  else
 34   {
 35    string first;
 36    string last;
 37    int key;
 38
 39    first = s.substr(0, s.find(" "));
 40    s.erase(0,s.find(" ")+1);
 41    last = s.substr(0, s.find(" "));
 42    s.erase(0,s.find(" ")+1);
 43    key = atoi(s.c_str());
 44
 45    my_graph.add_edge(first, last, key);
 46   }
 47  }
 48 }
 49
 50 void MSTapp::print_v()
 51 {
 52  my_graph.print_vertices();
 53 }
```

Graph.h

```
 5 #include"MSTapp.h"
 6 #include<map>
 7 #include<iostream>
 8 #include<string>
 9 #include<vector>
 10 #include<list>
 11
 12 using namespace std;
 13
 14 #ifndef GRAPH_H
 15 #define GRAPH_H
 16
 17 class Graph
 18 {
 19  public:
 20 //  Graph();
 21 //  ~Graph();
 22   void add_vertex(string name);
 23   void print_vertices();
 24   void add_edge(string from, string to, int weight);
 25  // void print_edges();
 26 //  void min_span_tree(string start);
 27
 28  private:
 29  // MinPriority min_queue;
 30
 31   class Vertex
 32   {
 33    public:
 34     string name;
 35     string pi;
 36     int key;
 37   };
 38   class Neighbor
 39   {
 40    public:
 41     string name;
 42     int weight;
 43   };
 44
 45  vector<Vertex> vertices;
 46  map <string name, list<Neighbor> > adj_list;
 4
 48 };
 49
 50 #endif
```

Graph.cpp

```
 5 #include"MSTapp.h"
 6 #include"Graph.h"
 7
 8 #include<iostream>
 9 #include<map>
 10 #include<algorithm> // sort
 11 #include<string>
 12 #include<vector>
 13 #include<list>
 14
 15 using namespace std;
 35 void Graph::add_vertex(string name)
 36 {
 37  Vertex v1;
 38  v1.name = name;
 39  v1.pi = "NIL";
 40  v1.key = 100;
 41  bool check;
 42
 43  for(int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i++)
 44  {
 45   if(vertices[i].name == v1.name)
 46   {
 47    check = true;
 48   }
 49  }
 50
 51  if(check == false)
 52  {
 53   vertices.push_back(v1);
 54  }
55 }
56
57 void Graph::print_vertices()
58 {
59  for(int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i++)
60  {
61   cout << vertices[i].name << " " << vertices[i].pi << " " << vertices[i].key << endl;
62  }
63 }
64
65 void Graph::add_edge(string from, string to, int weight)
66 {
67  string v_from = from;
68  string v_to = to;
69  int v_weight = weight;
70
71  Neighbor n1;
72  n1.name = v_to;
73  n1.weight = v_weight;
74
75  adj_list[v_from];
76  adj_list[v_from].push_back(n1);
77  adj_list[v_from].sort();
78 }
```

All the functions for the Vertices are working so just ignore those. The main problem I am having is the add_edge function in the Graph. For example my input would be something as follows:

```
A B C D E //Vertices, this is working
A B 3
```

so, with the A B 3, I would like to add the B and 3 the the neighbor, and do something like
adj_list[A].push_back(Neighbor)

The errors I am getting are regarding the map, it is saying I have the incorrect number of template arguments for the map in Graph.h.

Am I declaring my map incorrectly on line 46 of Graph.h?

If anyone could provide any insight as to what I am doing wrong or how I can get this working it would be GREATLY appreciated. If any additional clarifcation is needed, just ask. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide the actual compiler error you are getting.

Answer (score 4):

you should declare the map as:

```
map <string, list<Neighbor> > adj_list;
```